# Is it possible to get MIN and MAX VALUE with ONE priority_queue?

Tags: priority-queue

If I have a queue which is **{1, 3, 10, 22}**

and I need max and min value (22, 1)

so I made maxHeap and minHeap with priority_queue, and I got two priority_queue.
but I need just max and min. I think that I just make one maxheap and get max in root and get min in (where). If possible.

So is it possible to get MAX & MIN with just one maxheap or minheap?
Or I must make two priority queues?

Comment: Standard priority queues generally don't have that capability: you can get either the min (from a min heap) or the max (from a max heap). Some give you the ability to iterate over the items to find the other (min from a max heap, for example), but that's an O(n) operation. You can, however, implement a [Min-max heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_heap), which gives you O(1) access to min, and O(1) access to max.

Comment: @JimMischel
Thank you, I didn't know there is a min-max heap. GOOD!